# Custom format Korean date with forward-slash not working

Tags: c#, .net, date-formatting, cjk

If you run the following code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kBqe9x

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR")));
    }
}
```

The result will be **2022-01-18**.

Why is .net replacing the forward-slash with a dash?

Comment: I think it is because it (rightly or wrongly) thinks that Korean uses dashes for a separator so it converts your date time accordingly. If you know the format is correct, you do not need to pass a culture info.

Comment: The `/` character means "Use the system date separator" which (for Korean) is `-`. If you want to force `/`, specify it using an escape: `\\/` (note that you have to escape the \ itself by writing "\\")

Comment: `The / character means "Use the system date separator"` - I would argue that's odd behavior, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slash is a special character, in DateTime you have to write that like '/'

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR")));
    }
}
```

Comment: why is that? if I change the language to `en-US` or `pt-BR` the forward-slash works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `ko-KR` culture info has such a date pattern for a short date. If you take a look at the `ShortDatePattern` property of the `CultureInfo` you've created here, you'll see the following.

```
var cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR");
Console.WriteLine(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

This prints out: `yyyy-MM-dd`

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CRxKtQ

If you want to keep the pattern you specified in `ToString` method, simply remove the culture info.

Comment: I don't want to remove the culture info from `ToString`. I went with @robert approach.